# HandsOnTable - programmatically update manualColumnMove breaks the grid functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I want the functionality of dynamically toggling the setting manualColumnMove to true or false. When I change it to false using

```
hot.updateSettings({manualColumnMove: false})
```

after a column has been moved the table returns to its previous state and switching back to true is impossible.

Here's a fiddle with my problem [jsfiddle.net/n9bL1vLx/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/n9bL1vLx/4/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yup, that's a bug. File it in the github page.